# product with a constant term and a divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In doing some calculation, I am getting a step as

$k$(a divergent series over reals)$=0$ where $k$ is a real constant. Can I conclude that $k=0$?

Infact I have like this:

$k(\sum r^n)=0$ with $r>1$. Can I conclude $k=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, evidently you can. Because the sum of a strictly divergent series is never zero.
And as your series appears to be a geometric series, the sum will always be positive.